# Single string to array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-macros

I have selected a range from google sheet. When I select a column it usually becomes array. but when I selected a row it became single string.

How do I solve this? Mentioned below is my code:-

```
dMatch = sheet.getRange("A2:CE2").getValues();
```

This coverts the row into a single string array which I don't want.

I tried split method but it throws some error.

```
dMatch = dMatch.split(",");
```

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: what is the value of dMatch?

Comment: error is :- TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of undefined. (line 14, file "Code")

Comment: the value of array is: [19-12-25 16:44:41:092 IST] [[Shift Time,  (IST), , , Name, ldap, Name, 12/1/2019, 12/2/2019, 12/3/2019, 12/4/2019, 12/5/2019, 12/6/2019, 12/7/2019, , 12/8/2019, 12/9/2019, 12/10/2019, 12/11/2019, 12/12/2019, 12/13/2019, 12/14/2019, , 12/15/2019, 12/16/2019, 12/, , , , ]]

Comment: Sounds like you need a if statement to check if dMatch is null or undefined prior to executing split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Object to String.
2. Split comma(,)

```js
dMatch = sheet.getRange("A2:CE2").getValues();
dMatch = JSON.stringify(dMatch).split(",");
```